# The best way to “split” up a large Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have an already-large controller that’s getting bigger. I was wondering what would be the best way to slim down my controllers. I’m not necessarily looking for the easiest way, but a safe and efficient way. I’ve been developing with Rails for a while now but I’m still not familiar with how “subclassing” works and I’m not even sure if it’s supposed to be used in this way. I was thinking maybe something like this?

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
end

class MoreFunctionsController < SomeController
end
```

That’s currently untested – I’m still working on it right now – but I hope that this would sort of give you an idea of what direction I’m trying to go. I’m also not sure how the routing for this would look. What would be the best way to “split” up a large controller?

Comment: Why is your controller big? Too much public actions or too much logic?

Comment: I would also add look into [Fat Model / Skinny Controller](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model). Of course, people can often take this too far and start putting view logic concerns in the model, but taking a DRY approach and moving data logic back to the model is a good idea.

Comment: @delba well, it's a pretty big app overall.. My controllers were actually already pretty 'slim' but I was just looking for a way to make them slimmers as they get bigger..

Comment: @creativereason thanks for the info.. Pretty good read

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::Concern` [(documentation)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) is what you are looking for.

**Update**

Something like this:

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/concerns) # in Rails4 this is automatic

# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
class  MyController < ApplicationController
  include GeneralStuffConcern

  def index
    render text: foo
  end
end

# app/controllers/concerns/general_stuff_concern.rb
module GeneralStuffConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  
  def show
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  
protected
  def foo
    'fooo'
  end
end
```

**update 2**

I actually recommend this more http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

**update 3 (2022)**

Bounded contexts https://blog.eq8.eu/article/rails-bounded-contexts.html

Comment: ...also check https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources if you want to get rid of repeating stuff in controller

Comment: + if you want to learn more good techniques to simplify your objects check http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: Wow! Never even heard about this before.. Thank you :)

Comment: ...also Listeners are awesome way to remove stuff from controller https://github.com/equivalent/simple_listener    example: https://github.com/equivalent/simple_listener/wiki#example-1-rails